# Is it possible to find the rows whose sum is X with a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope the title is explicit enough. I'm going to make it clearer with a simple example below. Just to give some context though : I have a disparity between two parallell methods in a program that should return an equal result (we're using both as a control/safety, only one is supposed to be the "production" treatment in the long run). The difference amounts to a sum of X in a specific field of a given table. I'm trying to find the ids concerned by the issue so that I can hopefully find a common point between them and thus solve my problem. The real-life table has several thousands rows, so I don't think any kind of brute-force testing is going to work here.

Let's say I have a *Person* table, with an id, a name, and a "random number" field. Like this :

```
Id   Name     RandomNumber
1    John     5
2    Pedro    7
3    Alice    10
4    Alan     3
5    Cynthia  4
6    Alex     2
```

Let's say I want to find out all possible combinations to get the number 11 (in my real-life case there's likely only one combination, though getting more is fine since I can then analyze each separately). So the possible results are : 
Pedro + Cynthia
John + Cynthia + Alex

Now it doesn't matter if I have to use a different query for each result (if I need, for instance, one subquery per "parameter", so one with two subqueries and then one with three) or not. I'd want the simplest option, if there's one of course.

According to an old question that was proposed by the system while writing this (pretty effective I must say) it's an NP-complete problem ? Which would suck a bit for me, though that's not the end of the world because we have a workaround solution for this, but obviously solving the issue would be better.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, it'd be np-complete. it's basically a variant of the knapsack problem. there's NO single query that can do this for you. you could try fiddling with a recursive query, and just keep recursing until you find a set of records that adds up to your total, but that's not simple OR efficient.

Comment: The reason this isn't possible is that you don't know how many rows combine to make the sum.  If the question was which *n* rows summed to make *x* you could join the table to itself *n* times.  Without this you have an unspecified number of joins to find your answer... That can't be expressed in SQL.

Comment: Yes I tried to convey that I have an idea about *n* (realistically it's 2 or 3, perhaps 4) so I can try for a few different *n* values. I tried the double-join and got no result so I tried the triple-join but it took about 10 minutes and then I killed it. If it's the only solution perhaps I should try again and let it run a bit longer.

Comment: You should add the SQL you used when you tried the triple-join.  Perhaps we could help troubleshoot why it takes so long to run.

Comment: @James L. It was a full inner join (cartesian product ? is that a term in English ?) with no hem, "where" clause you know the ones used to make a normal inner join (like a.id = b.id and so forth). The idea was that for *each* result I wanted to check every other possible combination. Basically brute-force and it didn't work, which was kind of expected. If I join on id, then I would only be checking if there's a single id whose *n* rows are equal to X.

Comment: @JamesL. It's going to have to evaluate billions of join combinations. If the OP has 3,000 rows then to the power 3 that is `27,000,000,000`. They only need a triangular join not a cross join though and any values in the base table larger than the desired sum can be excluded up front but likely this will still be a large number.

Comment: @Air10 your join condition could be `where a.id>b.id and b.id >c.id` so you aren't going to evaluate different orderings of the same ids. But this is still quadratic complexity.

Comment: @Martin Smith : oh, didn't think about that one. Could be enough to bring the query into "useable" territory actually. I'll have to try this tomorrow and see what result it gives.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a query which will get this data.  You could use the suggestion from Marc B's comment, but truthfully you are looking at a massive amount of processing.

Addressing the problem, try the [SQL Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799.aspx).  It is easy to setup and provides a lot of useful information, including the SQL for the commands sent to the server.  You can also add filters to remove queries you do not care about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The program already has a textfile that logs every SQL query sent to the database. The problem is that when I extracted the relevant query and executed it directly, it returned the correct result. Yet the end return of the program was wrong, which suggests some later code snippet removed a few results when it shouldn't have. I'll look into that recursive query thingy maybe. (While I use SQL as part of my job, I'm nowhere near an expert in it since I generally only need simple SELECT statements with the occasional UPDATE)

Comment: @Air10  It sounds like either you are not logging the actual commands sent to the SQL server (so SQL Profiler is useful) or code is modifying the results returned from the server.  Either way, the recursive query (or similar) are not likely to be effective since you need to know what the code is changing, not why the SQL results do not match.

Comment: I want(ed?) the query to find the *ids* that are being wrongly removed. Right now I don't even have that, so I don't know why the code is removing those results. It could be that those cases have one common point that explains why the code would act on it. It's hard to explain without going into a ton of details on what the program itself is doing (which is irrelevant to the "Finding those *ids*" SQL question)

Comment: @Air10 Yes, too much dialog is needed to get to the bottom :).  If you can debug the application you could use a Boolean search to narrow down when the results change.  This will give you smaller and smaller sets of code to check, until you find where the data is modified.  The SQL data approach is going to be complicated and time consuming and it is not guaranteed to find the issue or give you the information you need to solve it.  You also might want to check with your team members to see if they know what is going on.

Comment: Sadly my mentor/supervisor (only other person working on that particular project) has no clue either. He has a ton of experience with that software as well as the business side of said software so the fact that he doesn't know (beyond "It worked when I removed those modifications", said modifications were written by our R&D department and are there to fix another issue so removing them is a workaround) isn't exactly reassuring. He's the workaholic who typically finds the answer to almost everything, and pretty quickly. Not this one, though. Hence my "stab in the dark" approach for now.